# ISO standard for units (kilos, meters, etc)

Tags: iso

I've been tasked to find a large list of iso standards - their real value, suchs as meters, and their 3 character standard. It should be available in both Danish and English.

I've spent all my google-fu on this, where should I be looking?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Where should it be posted, in that case?